# Micro Linux PC Solution for driving a simple kiosk that displays a static webpage

Tags: linux, embedded

Can anyone point me in the direction of some cheap low end hardware that I can attach a VGA monitor to and essentially have small information kiosk.

Preferably a fanless pc.

Comment: Not a serious answer:  if the page is static, why not just print a poster ;-)

Comment: Google might be a nice direction.

Comment: What I meant by static is that the page doesn't have any videos, flash, (anything else that could slow a brower down other than just basic rendering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've enjoyed Shuttle products in the past; [this machine](http://us.shuttle.com/X350.aspx) looks shiny and cheap.